# strtok - buffer overrun

Tags: c++, strtok

c++ function, **strtok()** [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

Will this example suffer from buffer overrun if **str** is not terminated properly?

```
/* strtok example */
/* source - cplusplus.com (see link below) */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-"); // walk the stack?
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If **str** isn't terminated correctly with "\0", isn't it possible for

> ```
> pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
> ```

to walk the stack?

Thanks!

Comment: The simple way to think of this is that if `str` isn't properly terminated, then *it's not a C-style string*. It's just some characters. Passing anything other than a C string to `strtok` is bad news, of course.

Comment: Is this for some white hat hacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most string-handling functions will walk off the end if the string is not null-terminated.

However, in your code example, `str` is terminated.

Comment: Roger that. My example shows it, but if I was using a function without string termination, a buffer overrun could happen.

thanks!